# Python Print format suggestion

Tags: python

I am using python2 for printing some data.
I am looking to print the output in the following format.

```sh
echo 'Stats,tableName=test ItemCount=1,TableSizeBytes=85'
```

With my code it is giving in the below format.
Any Help would be appreciated.

**Ouput:**

```
echo Stats tableName= test ItemCount= 1 TableSizeBytes= 85
```

***Code:***

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import boto.dynamodb
import boto

for table in lts:
    tableinfo = conn.describe_table(table)
    TableName = tableinfo['Table']['TableName']
    ItemCount = tableinfo['Table']['ItemCount']
    TableSize = tableinfo['Table']['TableSizeBytes']
    print('echo','Dynamostats','TableName=',TableName,'ItemCount=',ItemCount,'TableSizeBytes=',TableSize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
print("echo 'Stats,tableName={0} ItemCount={1},TableSizeBytes={2}'".format(TableName, ItemCount, TableSize))
```

**Output :**

```
>>>"echo 'Stats,tableName=test ItemCount=1,TableSizeBytes=85'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `format` like the following to get the result you want:

```
>>> "echo 'Stats,tableName={} ItemCount={},TableSizeBytes={}'".format(TableName, ItemCount, TableSize)
"echo 'Stats,tableName=test ItemCount=1,TableSizeBytes=85'"
>>>
```

Comment: How to print the output to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```py
print (f"echo ’Stats,tableName={TableName} ItemCount={ItemCount},TableSizeBytes={TableSize}'")
```

**Output**

```sh
echo ’Stats,tableName=test ItemCount=1,TableSizeBytes=85'
```